# issue with 2 jquery functions on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have no idea how to use javascript but I'm running into an issue where I have a slider on the homepage and i have a function for a pop up. The problem is that every time i open the pop up the slideshow images open up with the pop up and cover it. This is what I have 
http://jsfiddle.net/kD4ZB/  the problem occurs when you click contact. Thank you very much

Comment: The JS Fiddle is showing a blank image, can you check on it?

Comment: "I have no idea how to use javascript" - then learn a little about the language. Stack Overflow is not a code-fixing shop for folks who don't put a bit of effort in. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be less about jQuery and more about z-index of your CSS.  Try editing the pop-up to have a higher z-index or set the z-index of the slider to be less.  z-index can be considered "the distance from the screen" where 0 (well, technically -1) is on the screen and 100 (well sometimes 1,000) is on the user.  If A has a z-index of 10 and B has a z-index of 11 then B will obscure A.